# Basic firestore get request problem in simple Gatsby website

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, gatsby

I have created a simple get request, but I am unsure what to do as it has asked for a key. This is a reduced version of my code:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from "gatsby-plugin-firebase";

var db = firebase.firestore();

var word1 = db.collection("menue").doc("word1");

 class newMenue extends Component {


     constructor(props) {
         super(props)    
         this.state = {
              wordOne: "",            
         }
     }

    render() {

        word1.get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log('No such document!');
          } else {
            console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
            this.setState({
                wordOne: doc.data()
            }) 
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting document', err);
        });


        return (
            <div>
                 <h2 >{this.state.wordOne}</h2>
                 <br/> 

                         <br/>
<h5>4 Slices of grilled Cypriot Halloumi</h5>
        </div>
        )

        }
    }

export default newMenue
```

this is my database:

```
Document data: {One: "hi"}
```

This is what the dev tools states.

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {One}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array
>   instead.

What do I do in order to add the key to display the information?

Specifically, I am trying to set up a website for my friend's burger place where he can put in the menu changes on the website himself and I am stuck at this last bit.

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.wordOne`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to render an object:

`<h2>{this.state.wordOne}</h2> // which is {One: "hi"}`

You need to render the property of the object:

```
<h2>{this.state.wordOne.One}</h2>
```

Comment: that is painfully simple

Comment: @AlexanderHemming No problem, simple ones like this get me all the time. Mark the answer as correct if you don't mind!